# Connect to Gitlab from python through SSH to deploy public key

Tags: python, ssh, gitlab

I have to code a python script which creates a new gitlab project, generate RSA keys and deploy the generated public key to the newly created GitLab project/repository.

I have already created a the Git project using Git's REST api. I also managed to generate RSA keys with python.

However, I don't really know how to connect to GitLab through SSH and deploy the public key...
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use GitLab's API to add a key for the currently authenticated user via the `POST /user/keys` endpoint. See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/users.html#add-ssh-key

As admin, you can add public keys also for other users via `POST /users/:id/keys`

I am not sure what you mean by *deploy the generated public key to the newly created GitLab project/repository*. The only project specific (as opposed to user-specfic, see above) keys I can think of are Deploy Keys.
Fortunately, GitLab provides an API for that as well via `POST /projects/:id/deploy_keys`.
See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/deploy_keys.html#add-deploy-key

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I managed to do everything i needed to with the git api that you stated. Cheers :)